# How to use FlowDocument on Android?

Tags: c#, android, wpf

I have been searching for a solution, but I couldn't succeed. The problem is as follows.

I have a WPF application where I am using `FlowDocument`s. I want to create a corresponding application on Android and share documents between those applications (WPF and Android) using a web service.

Android has SpannableString. But I couldn't figure out if we have a control in Android, like RichTextBox in WPF.

To sum up my question, Is there a **format** like **Rich Text Format** and an Android control to both display and manipulate this document on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the TextView together with the span fields to set different text styles (similar to Runs on XAML). There is also a [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) which might ease this process.

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hello World!")
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 5, 0);  
text.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 7, 11, 0);
```